# Pymongo find using int64 fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to do a find within a MongoDB collection using the Pymongo python driver.

I'm using a key called "book id" which has a datatype of "int64", however the docs only mention the ability to search for documents that contain "book id" with an int64 datatype. e.g.

```
 db.books.find( { "book id": { $type : 18 } })
```

How can I perform the same search using Python and also include the key value to search for. e.g.

```
"book id": 12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric [types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) are the one case where MongoDB will do the conversion for you.  As such, you don't need to do anything special for `int64` fields:

```
db.books.find({ "book id": 12345 })
```

Comment: Yeah thanks - just worked out why it wasn't working for me. My key had whitespace in it. e.g. { "book id ": 12345 }